# How to align a group of nodes with respect to the widest one

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

Consider the following figure:

[image]

How can I align the horizontal-text nodes so that their `.west` nodes are vertically aligned with respect to the widest node in the group?

Also, how can I add the vertical-text node so that it is automatically a bit to the left of the widest horizontal-text node?

*Note:* the widest horizontal-text node must be placed next to the grid as shown in the picture.

Here is the code for my example:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [thick] (0,0) grid (5,5);
  \foreach \y/\text in {
    1/A,
    2/Two words,
    3/Something longer,
    4/The,
    5/begininning of a sentence%
  }{
    \node at (0,\y) [left] {\text};
  }
  \node at (-3.5,2.5) [rotate=90] {\textbf{Some Label}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using the `positioning` library.  It requires setting the offset explicitly.   You might find using a `\matrix` as another viable approach.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [thick] (0,0) grid (5,5);
  \begin{scope}[node distance=4.1cm]
    \foreach \y/\text in {
    1/A,
    2/Two words,
    3/Something longer,
    4/The,
    5/begininning of a sentence%
  }{
    \node (A\y) [left=of {(0,\y)},anchor=west] {\text};
  }
  \end{scope}
  \node at (-3.5,2.5) [rotate=90,left=of A3,anchor=base] {\textbf{Some Label}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```